# CSS vertical-align not working for certain rows/columns of the table

Tags: html, css

hi I have been trying table attributes and one of them was valign. But I stumbled with some cells not getting affected by it, so I tried CSS vertical-align and now I stumbled with some cells getting affected and some that are not. I did notice that cells with enough rowspan get affected. The padding is quite abnormal with this sample because I was testing whether or not the cells that did not get affected did not have enough space.

```css
.time-col {
    background-color: gold;
    color: maroon;
}
.day-cols {
    color: red;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.six-am {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;

    
    
}

td  {
    padding: 100px;
    vertical-align: bottom;


}

.seven-am {
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: yellow;
}

.eight-am {
    background-color: pink;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<table border="4" frame="box" rules="all" style="text-align: center" summary="A table showing the broadcast schedule of news." cellpadding="20px" cellspacing="5px" width="1000" height="100" >
        <caption>All times listed in central time</caption>
        <colgroup>
            <col class="time-col">
            <col class="day-cols" span="7">
        </colgroup>

        <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
            <th>Sunday</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody valign="bottom" >
            <tr>
            <th>6:00</th>
            <td colspan="7" >National News</td>
            
        <tr>
            <th>6:30</th>
            <td colspan="7">Local News</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        
        <tbody class="seven-am">
            <tr>
            <th>7:00</th>
            <td rowspan="2">Opera Fest</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Radio U</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Science Week</td>
            <td rowspan="2">The Living World</td>
            <td>Word Play</td>
            <td>Agri-Week</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Folk Fest</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>7:30</th>
            <td>Brain Stew</td>
            <td>Bismarck Forum</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        
        <tbody class="eight-am">
            <tr>
            <th>8:00</th>
            <td rowspan="4" colspan="4">The Classical Music Connection</td>
            <td>Old Time Radio</td>
            <td rowspan="4">Saturday Night Jazz</td>
            <td rowspan="4">The Indie Connection</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>8:30</th>
            <td>The Inner Mind</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>9:00</th>
            <td rowspan="2">Open Mike Nite</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>9:30</th>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        
        
        <tr>
            <th>10:00</th>
            <td colspan="7">World News Feeds</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: don't forget that you also have **th** elements and not only **td**

Comment: Ah yes, but the td elements are still not being vertically aligned, does vertical-align only work to those with rowspan > 1?

Comment: which one is not aligned correctly? all of them are correctly aligned to the bottom

Comment: The cells that contain National News, World News Feed, and the cells on Friday and Saturday columns that have a single rowspan does not seem to align to the bottom.

Comment: they are but you have added a big padding they cannot cross the padding, they will have 100px at the bottom which is the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason vertical-align isn't working is at the moment is some cells have a padding that is determining their heights. What you need is a smaller padding and a fixed height so that the text has the freedom to be aligned as specified.

```
td {
    padding: 80px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: 300px;
}
```